# Create list of reactive values that can be accessed using elements

Tags: r, list, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to make a list that contains reactive inputs:

```
vec_inputs <-list(input$widget1, input$widget2)
```

I know there needs to be a `reactive({})` or `reactiveValues()` statement in there somewhere.
This list has to be accessed using elements.
i.e:
vec_inputs[1], so that it can be used in a for loop:

```
for ( i in length(vec_inputs$list) ) {
    
    print(vec_inputs$list[i])

})
```

which prints the values of input$widget1 and input$widget 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
variable <- reactive({
list(input$widget1, input$widget2, etc.)
})
```

and then you should be able to call the vector as:

```
variable()
```

to use in your for loop

```
for ( i in length(variables()) ) {
    
    print(variables()[i])

})
```

ps. all of this needs to go in the `server({...})` part of the application

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1:length(variable()[i])?

Comment: Is there a way to implement this, with logical operators?
It currently throws the error, "```Error in variable()[1] == variable()[2] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented```"